# JavaScript regex that finds all comments

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to strip out all comments in a sample of JavaScript using regex in JavaScript.

The regex I have is as follows:

```
/((\/\*+)(\*|\s)*([^]*[\*]*)(\*|\s)*(\*+\/))/g
```

The sample I'm running it against is:

```
/*basic comment*/

console.log('turtle');

/*********************
Fancy liney comment
*********************/

console.log('turtle');

/****long basic comment ****/

console.log('turtle');

/*
 *
 * Oh look, it's one of these... great.
 *
 */
```

For your convenience, I've created a demo of this at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/kI8iH7/1).

As you can see on regex101, if you are using pearly regex (PCRE), this all works perfectly, all four comments are found and registered as matches.  However, I'm doing this in JavaScript, if you select the JavaScript flavour on regex101, you'll see that the entire block is highlighted as one single match, meaning my lovely turtle logs are killed off when I go to delete the comments.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this part doing what you think it does? `[^]*[\*]`

Comment: `var trollString = "aaaand... /* you fail! */ :p";`

Comment: Make your `*` non-greedy, but as @NiettheDarkAbsol points out, this is a fragile solution. Anyway, unless I'm missing something, `\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/` would seem simpler.

Comment: Anyway, the best regex for multiline comments is [`/\/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^\/*][^*]*\*+)*\//g`](https://regex101.com/r/uZ3qX8/1). It matches them as a whole block though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to explain what is going on: the `]` in `[^]` is interpreted as *match any character that is not nothing* in JS, and in PCRE, it means *match a non-`]`* (as there is another unescaped `]` later in the pattern). Thus, the character class in JS is `[^]`, and in PCRE, the character class found by the regex engine is `[^]*[\*]`.

*All you need to do is **escape the `]` inside the character class***:

```
/((\/\*+)(\*|\s)*([^\]*[\*]*)(\*|\s)*(\*+\/))/g
                    ^^
```

The thing is, a `]` inside a character class in JS regex flavor should be escaped *even when it is the first character in the class*. In PCRE, and most other falvors, `]` does not have to be escaped when it is the first character in the character class.

See [the JS demo](https://regex101.com/r/oA3dJ9/1)

However, the most efficient pattern to match multiline comments is

```
/\/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^\/*][^*]*\*+)*\//g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uZ3qX8/1)

It will work the same in almost any regex flavor.

Comment: That's a nice answer +1, However Paul L's answer is great too.

Comment: Perfect Wiktor, just perfect.  I've stuck it in my code, my unit tests are suddenly all turning green, thank you muchly! :)  And thank you everyone else who gave feedback and answers!

Answer (score 1):

https://regex101.com/r/kI8iH7/2

It looks like PCRE and Javascript regexps treat the `[^]` differently.  To be honest, I don't know what I would expect that to do.  Normally in a character class, `^` at the front means to negate the class, so the class actually matches all the characters **not** listed.  But if `^` is anything other than the first character in the class, it matches only itself.  It seems like there's a difference of opinion between PCRE and Javascript as to what to do if `^` is the only character in the class.

In your case, you seem to have wanted it to mean "match anything", so I simply replaced that with the far more common `.*`.  (I also got rid of the character class following it, as there's never a need for only one thing, to be in a class by itself.  Just match the actual token, no need to match a class only containing one token.)

`((\/\*+)(\*|\s)*(.*\**)(\*|\s)*(\*+\/))`

Comment: *It looks like PCRE and Javascript regexps treat the `[^]` differently* - they *do* parse this pattern differently since these are different regex flavors. `[^]` means *any character that is not nothing* in JS.

Comment: Yes, and it would seem that `[^]` isn't even legal in PCRE.  Instead, the entire snippet `[^]*[\*]` was being considered one single character class, matching any of `]`, `*`, `[`, or `\*` (though it obviously ignored the `\\` in that case).

Comment: In, PCRE `[]` and `[^]` are not legal, and considered a user error - thus an error is generated. In JS, no idea why, they decided to accept `[]` as a matching nothing construct, and `[^]` as a construct matching anything that is not nothing.